# What data type is a whole number in #define?

Tags: c

If I use a whole number in `#define`, what `data type` is it considered to be in `sprintf()` in `C99` ?

```
#define NUMBER 100

sprintf(buf, "%i\n", NUMBER); // is it %i, %u, %lu ?
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be equivalent to `sprintf("%i\n", 100)`?

Comment: Rule of Thumb: A macro is text copy-and-paste. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define NUMBER1 100 /* int: use "%d" or "%i" in printf() */
#define NUMBER2 100U /* unsigned int: use "%u" in printf() */
#define NUMBER3 100L /* long int: use "%ld" or "%li" in printf() */
#define NUMBER4 100UL /* unsigned long int: use "%lu" in printf() */
/* C99 */
#define NUMBER5 100LL /* long long int: use "%lld" or "%lli" in printf() */
#define NUMBER6 100ULL /* unsigned long long int: use "%llu" in printf() */
```

Note: the U and L can also be in lowercase
Note2: the U can come before or after the L or LL

Answer (score 3):

The type of that literal is `int`. You should use `%d` or `%i`.

`NUMBER` literally gets replaced with `100` when compiling by the preprocessor. The fact that it's a macro means nothing to the compiler, because the compiler never sees `NUMBER`; the compiler only ever sees `100`.

Answer (score 2):

All `#define`-d items are straightforward text substitutions: imagine that the `100` is pasted in instead of the `NUMBER` identifier:

```
sprintf(buf, "%i\n", NUMBER);
//      ^^^ It's sprintf, don't forget the buffer!
```

Since `100` is an integer literal, you should use `%d`.